# Loop through the div with same class in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I have lots of class with name `itemdata`and I want to do some jquery inside each div. In each div, there is one link, I want to copy that `href` attribute value and wrap it to another `<span>` inside that respective div.

My code is like below.

```html
<div class="itemdata" >
<a  href="www.link1" class="frame">
<img  src='...' />
</a>
<span class="wlt_shortcode_TITLE">Title 1</span>
</div>

<div class="itemdata" >
<a  href="www.link2" class="frame">
<img  src='...' />
</a>
<span class="wlt_shortcode_TITLE">Title 2</span>
</div>

<div class="itemdata" >
<a  href="www.link3" class="frame">
<img  src='...' />
</a>
<span class="wlt_shortcode_TITLE">Title 3</span>
</div>
```

And jQuery:

```js
</script>
jQuery( ".itemdata" ).each(function() {
var lk = jQuery( this ).add(".frame").attr("href");
jQuery(this).add(".wlt_shortcode_TITLE" ).wrap("<a href='" + lk + "'></a>");
});
</script>
```

Output HTML should look like:

```html
    <div class="itemdata" >
    <a  href="www.link1" class="frame">
    <img  src='...' />
    </a>
    <a  href="www.link1"><span class="wlt_shortcode_TITLE">Title 1</span></a>
    </div>

    <div class="itemdata" >
    <a  href="www.link2" class="frame">
    <img  src='...' />
    </a>
    <a  href="www.link2"><span class="wlt_shortcode_TITLE">Title 2</span></a>
    </div>

    <div class="itemdata" >
    <a  href="www.link3" class="frame">
    <img  src='...' />
    </a>
    <a  href="www.link3"><span class="wlt_shortcode_TITLE">Title 3</span></a>
    </div>
```

But it looks like:

```html
        <div class="itemdata" >
        <a  href="www.link1" class="frame">
        <img  src='...' />
        </a>
        <a  href="undefined">
         <a  href="www.link1">
          <a  href="www.link1"><span class="wlt_shortcode_TITLE">Title 1</span>
          </a>
         </a>
        </a>
        </div>

        <div class="itemdata" >
        <a  href="www.link2" class="frame">
        <img  src='...' />
        </a>
        <a  href="undefined">
         <a  href="www.link1">
          <a  href="www.link1"><span class="wlt_shortcode_TITLE">Title 2</span>
          </a>
         </a>
        </a>
        </div>

        <div class="itemdata" >
        <a  href="www.link3" class="frame">
        <img  src='...' />
        </a>
        <a  href="undefined">
         <a  href="www.link1">
          <a  href="www.link1">
            <span class="wlt_shortcode_TITLE">Title 3</span>
          </a>
         </a>
        </a>
        </div>
```

Comment: The question is quite confusing the way you've presented it. I mean no offence by this, but you should likely take a few minutes to really think out the question and word it so that it can be clearly understood.

Comment: Hi, @wrxsti, I have explained all the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close. You're using [`.add`](https://api.jquery.com/add/) instead of [`.find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/). If you just modify that it works properly:

```
jQuery( ".itemdata" ).each(function() {
    var lk = jQuery( this ).find(".frame").attr("href");
    jQuery(this).find(".wlt_shortcode_TITLE" ).wrap("<a href='" + lk + "'></a>");
});
```

See Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rmf7yu7d/

Comment: Thanks @Stryner, I was dump at that.